# Piezoelectricity in water mediums

Tags: piezo-buzzer, piezo, waterproof, piezoelectricity, underwater

I am trying to run an experiment using a [piezo ceramic cylindrical transducer (32X30X10MM 29 KHZ)](https://www.steminc.com/PZT/en/piezo-ceramic-cylinder-32x30x10mm-29-khz) to send a signal from the inside of a water-filled test metal tube to a transducer mounted on the outside of the tube, and I could use some input on how to get the transducer to operate in water.

1. I am trying to avoid potting the transducer in a urethane for fear of bubbles (i don't have a vac chamber), can I operate in a pipe filled with distilled water for short time periods?
2. Or would I need to use mineral oil (messy!)?  If so, what kind?
3. On these cylindrical transducers, where do I solder +/-?  I assume inside and outside surfaces.  Should I use a special wire to prevent interference?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What does the device's data sheet tell you? If there is no data sheet available then contact the manufacturer. If they can't help then choose a different supplier. This is the path you should take on all electronic components that you plan to buy/use. This same (or similar) message gets put on this site probably several times a day because it is the most useful advice you will get. Don't buy anything that is not supported by the written word period.

Comment: Please note: Distilled water is more aggressive than normal tap-water! I heard water 'prefers' to have stuff dissolved in it, and it will tear down your contraption to attain that preferred state.

Comment: Thanks! The manufacturer did not respond to emails or phone calls, so it was helpful to get input before buying.  I have also searched the net, and I cannot find anywhere where there is a recommended type of mineral oil to pot transducers in, and only limited data on the actual potting process.

Answer (score 1):

You connect the wires to the surfaces of the cylinder that have electrodes, usually made of silver or nickel.  In this case, these should be the inside and outside surfaces.  These electrodes were used to apply the high voltage DC polarizing voltage that makes the ceramic into a piezoceramic.  To operate in water you need to insulate the cylinder since water is too conductive.  You can use urethane if you mix it slowly and wait for most of the bubbles to release.  A few small air bubbles will not significantly affect the operation.  You might want to try RTV rubber compound instead. Be careful when soldering as the ceramic is heat sensitive. First melt a small amount of solder onto the electrode.  Then apply the wire and quickly heat the solder.